# 2013, create site collection from wsp template?

Tags: 2013, site-collection, site-template

How do I create a new site collection from a SharePoint 2013 using a wsp template file as the template for the root site?

I've tried creating a new site collection and selecting "select template later" but when I browse to the site it returns a "403 Forbidden", in the guides for SharePoint 2010 the user is directed to a template picker page, any ideas?

Comment: You must add your account as the site collection administrator at site collection creation in order to not get an access denied, is that the problem? The process is the same for 2010 and 2013 regarding site templates.

Comment: Nope, turns out there was something funny going on with the web apps user permissions, all sorted now, thanks anyway :)